# Trig problem, finding angles and ranges

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have what may well be a simple problem, but it's been too long since I've done this type of problem. From a fixed point (intersection of all the lines), the angles to 3 other fixed points $a,b,c$ (the precise coordinate of $a,b,c$ are known) were measured relative to a set (unknown) direction (green line in diagram), this gives angles $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$.  How can I work out the exact location of the intersection, and the angle of the green reference line relative to North?

Here's a link to the image (not enough rep to post image directly)
 [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7y1G.png]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Place the line segments on the graph such that the intersection is on the origin $(0,0)$ and line $a$ is the $x-axis$. Now that you have the angles of them.

You can find the slope i.e (slope($m)=\tan \theta$)

Comment: If you translate the system so that the intersection is at the origin won't you lose the information of the points $a,b$ and $c$?  I'm not sure how your answer helps in finding the intersection relative to the known points.